# Is there a list of [shortcodes] for use in comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments

The only one I know and use is `[mcve]`. I was hoping there were others, for more (or all) help topics, but at least for the following two:

- `[How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)`
- `[How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)`

I tried `[hta]` (and it obviously doesn't work - it would be confusing), `[help-ask]`, `[help:ask]`, `[howtoask]`, `[how-to-ask]`. Nope.

It would be nice to be able to link any help topic with `[help-{term}]` or `[help-{slug}]`.

When searching for similar questions I only found on `[short-links]` and `[keyboard-shortcuts]`. Not on short acronyms to commonly linked help topics, for usage in comments.

Thanks.

---

EDIT: Indeed my question is a duplicate of the other one. But in their current form, both the question and the answer are not indexing the list of [comment formatting shortcodes](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) very well, which was what I was searching for and was provided by Mike, in the comments below.

So I added a link to the list as a comment under that question to make the link a bit more obvious. (it's also mentioned in the answer, but it's linked as "this link" - easy to miss).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: Thank you, @MikeMcCaughan. I wasn't able to find it on my own. Do you think I should delete this question? Or, since I wasn't able to find it, i'm thinking if you add it as an answer it might help others (like me) find it?

Comment: Keep it on here. I searched for "shortcodes" on meta.stackoverflow.com and didn't find anything very useful (besides this question :)).

Comment: In all my tries I never thought of trying `[ask]`. But it's for the better. Now I have all the list to play with. :). I really think it would be helpful for many if you added it as an answer.  If you don't until tomorrow, I will, referencing your comment :). Again, very big thank you.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking I've seen a duplicate question on Meta SO some time in the past, so I'm searching for that before I write an answer.

Comment: Hmm may have been on [the older/other Meta.SE that I was thinking of](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000)...

Comment: It's indeed on the same subject, but I don't find it particularly well indexed. I mean... ***"magic links"***? Who would search for that instead of comment `shortcodes`/`shortcuts`/`shortlinks`. There's nothing *magic* about them. It's still a bunch of `1`s and `0`s. We're coders, right?.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Sure.  I would keep it to make this stuff easier to find when searching meta

Comment: Well that made my trip to meta useful - I didn't know about these...

Comment: BTW, you're welcome :)

Comment: @Will _"BTW, you're welcome :) "_ Says _@Will_ _the grand joker_ :-P ...